# How to avoid selecting next value before inserting

Tags: sql, firebird

I need help with a SQL command. I would like to create several data in the database, but the table has a "counter" (generator). Before I create data in a new row, I have to call up and increase the counter with "SELECT NEXT VALUE".

What command do I have to enter if I use insert into for the generator once but want to insert data at the same time (values)

Comment: If this field in question is an autoincrement of some sort, you should be able to skip it completely in INSERT INTO statement. In fact, this is what autoincrement exists for. Updating the autoincremented field manually is a very controversial idea (especially if the database doesn't support atomic read-and-update).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`NEXT VALUE FOR <sequence-name>`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-commons-nxtvlufor) directly in your insert statement, so there is no need to select it separately. If you also need the generated value for subsequent statements, you can use the [`RETURNING`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-dml-insert-returning) clause to return the value.

For example

```sql
insert into some_table (id, other_column) 
   values (next value for seq_some_table_id, 'some value') 
   returning id
```

In addition, you can even simplify this further if you use an [identity column](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-ddl-tbl-identity) or a `before insert` trigger to generate the value for you.

For example:

Identity column

```sql
create table some_table (
  id integer generated by default as identity primary key,
  other_column varchar(50)
);
```

or generated using trigger

```sql
create table some_table (
  id integer primary key,
  other_column varchar(50)
);

create sequence seq_some_table_id;

set term #;
create trigger some_table_bi_id
active before insert on some_table
as
begin
  if (new.id is null) then
    new.id = next value for seq_some_table_id;
end#
set term ;#
```

The insert then no longer needs to specify the `ID` column:

```sql
insert into some_table (other_column) 
   values ('some value') 
   returning id
```

Comment: I still have a problem. When I try to insert an entry into the database using the Insert Into method, it gives me the error message "The insert failed because a column definition includes validation constraints.Validation error for column "the_table".COUNTER, value "*** zero ***". I need a code with which I can insert an entry into the table and the database generates the counter itself.

Comment: I am a beginner and would like to apologize in advance if I do not understand everything immediately

Comment: @Specter771908 That means your table has a column `COUNTER` and you set it to 0, while there is a check constraint that doesn't allow that value. I suggest you ask a new question and add the DDL of the table, and the insert statement you tried, and the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

It very simple you can add ID column or any name with int datatype and for that you enable identity as true, it will auto increment when new data is inserted. No need to any code for that.

Note: No need to pass value for ID, SQL do itself.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. How would that appear when I enter the sql code? Do you have an example?

Comment: You told insert data into table correct ? You insert value except ID column.it will start from 1,2,3......

Comment: when I insert a new column with value by command, I get the following error message "The insert failed because a column definition includes validation constraints. Validation error for column "COUNTER" (Generator).

Comment: Show your table design  and insert command, send table create script

Comment: becuse you have to inform the server you do intend to omit the value for that column, anbd that is not your mistake but a special case - see https://firebirdfaq.org/faq29/